# installation on OS X Yosemite

Tags: ros, macosx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has any brave soul tried this yet? Any luck?

I'm keen to upgrade, but have a working ROS installation running natively on my Mac for first time ever.

Not particularly keen to break it!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196773/installation-on-os-x-yosemite/) by [lteacy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1940/lteacy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-11-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-11-05**:
I tried it, and when I attempt to install the dependencies via rosdep, I get an error regarding the fact that vtk-java is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just bit the bullet, and it worked for me as *a update* from 10.9.5 to 10.10. However im using brew python, and not the system python that mac comes with. Im not sure if system python gets updated during this update or not, but i can confirm i have it working on hydro for yosemite. Gazebo, rviz, rqt, and roscore packages all work.

Using brew python 2.7.8

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) with karma: 1526 on 2014-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chintak](https://answers.ros.org/users/20949/chintak/) on 2014-12-02**:
I upgraded to Yosemite, but I'm unable to install the dependencies as well - `collada-dom` and `pcre`. You had the installation right from 10.8 or did you fresh install in 10.9? Since 10.9, stdlib for clang is libc++ instead of libstdc++. Link to question: http://bit.ly/1yHpSCv. Thanks!

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-12-02**:
im pretty sure i bought my mac during 10.9, but one way or another fresh 10.9 install --> 10.10 upgrade. I installed ROS and solved all dependency issues while still on 10.9, and then when i upgraded, nothing broke and everything worked

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-12-02**:
(everything worked, meaning everything that previously worked on 10.9)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not aware of anyone having successfully completed desktop-full (I think you may get away with desktop, based on where errors are being reported). There is an ongoing OSX tracker with a ton of info for OSX+indigo on the rosdistro github: https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/issues/4597

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-11-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1